# How to get date after 12 months in c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datetime-format

I have been given a task to get future date. I mean if today is  `1/1/2016` (1st Jan,2016) and when i add 12 months to it then normally it gives `1/1/2017` if i do like this code :

```
dateTimeObj="1/1/2016"
string futureDate=dateTimeObj.AddMonth(12);
```

Now this future date will give `1/1/2017` using this code but i have been asked to get when we add 12 months then it must give `12/31/2016` (31 dec,2016) (not  `1/1/2017`)

**How to achieve this ? Is there any inbuilt function to do this, If not then how to do it programtically?**

**Note:** The software on which i am coding is for accounts, they need the date this way only.

Comment: It looks like all you have to do is add `.AddDays(-1)`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Why "12/31/2016" and not "1/1/2017"? How would you deal with other dates? What are the rules?

Comment: you mean dateTimeObj="1/1/2016"
string futureDate=dateTimeObj.AddMonth(12).AddDays(-1);

Comment: @JeroenMostert sure, 1.1.2000 + one year = 1.1.2001, nothing wrong with it

Comment: You'd need to define your algorithm for what that actually means - is "12 months" defined as "1 year minus 1 day", or is there something else going on? You only provided one example, so it's hard to predict what you're actually going for. For example, how do you handle February 29th? And are you always adding 12 months or can you add 1 month, and if you can add 1 month, what is 1/31/2016 plus 1 month?

Comment: dateTimeObj.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1)

Comment: What if the date is 6/1/2016? what should that return?

Comment: Lets be clear though, 12 months after `1/1/2016` is `1/1/2017` not `12/31/2016`. If that's the desired result they expect they didn't ask you the right question.

Comment: @All, thankd for the answer. Me too i am also confused by what they have asked me to do. And why they want me to get 12months-1 date as 12 month. But i am working on accounts software. May be in accounts they have like this. Or may be its because of leap year or non leap year.

Comment: It's probably to find the start and end of a financial year using a specified start date. Just adding 12 months or a year gives you the start of the next year. Subtracting one day gives you the last day of the "year".

Comment: What they probably meant was "Whats the last day of a 12 month period starting on 1/1/2016?"

Comment: Never write code unless you understand why you're writing that code. Even if it is "because someone said to write exactly this", that's fine, but you must still have a reason. If you don't understand *why* they want this particular date, you have no idea whether your code is correct. So *ask*, don't speculate about leap years. Give them a few example dates and ask what they expect the outcome to be in each case.

Comment: Also, you need to be very careful doing date arithmetic. Your example is easy, but if they asked you the last day of a 12 month period starting from 2/29/2016 youre in for a rough ride.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no special Feature. Just so something like this:

```
date.AddMonths(12).AddDays(-1);
```

best regards

Comment: Yep, or instead of `AddMonth(12)`, `AddYear(1)`

Comment: AddDay is not the method edit it to AddDays and same for AddMonth edit it to AddMonths

Answer (score 6):

I think you should do this

```
dateTimeObj.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

When adding 12 months to today, the expected result is same date in next year. So what you have to do is subtract a timespan of one day from it. You can try the above methods in the comments or you can follow this.

This is giving the expected result as 12-31-2016

```
var dateTimeString = "1/1/2016";
DateTime dateTimeObj = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeString);
DateTime futureDate = dateTimeObj.AddMonths(12).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
Console.WriteLine(futureDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
Console.ReadLine();
```